# Windows password filter dll not being loaded

Tags: windows, dll, registry, lsa

I'm trying to load some password filter dlls in Windows 10. For your reference, they are [AtomicRedTeamPWFilter.dll](https://github.com/redcanaryco/atomic-red-team/blob/master/atomics/T1556.002/bin/AtomicRedTeamPWFilter.dll) and [OpenPasswordFilter](https://github.com/jephthai/OpenPasswordFilter).

I followed the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/installing-and-registering-a-password-filter-dll, as well as the instructions given by the publishers of the respective dlls. However, the dlls are not loaded upon restarting the machine.

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36347594/11105090), in my system event logs, I cannot find any entries related to the password filter dlls. I also checked the loaded modules in System Information, but cannot find the password filter dlls. Furthermore, I checked that the RunAsPPL registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa does not exist, meaning that LSA protection is disabled ([reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/how-to-get-a-password-filter-dll-signed-so-it/ccfa9b86-303a-4f90-a5ad-26445585d969)).

Any ideas as to what is wrong?